# slot parameter for QMetaObject::invokeMethod

Tags: c++, qt

Playing with `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` method :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::setText( int value)
{
    QString s = QString::number(value);
    ui->textEdit->setText(s);
}





void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QGenericArgument genericArg =  Q_ARG(int, 321);
    bool inv = QMetaObject::invokeMethod( this,"setText",Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection, genericArg);
    qDebug("inv = %d\n", inv);
}
```

`QMetaObject::invokeMethod` returns false.

I'm not sure regarding slot `"setText"`. I took it from function name and I suppose it might be related. Where I can find list of slots at all? Should I create special slot for `"setText"`?

Maybe it is related to fact I run it from the same thread?

UPD:

I have added public slot instead of public method:

```
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    //void setText( int value);


private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

public slots:
void setText(int value);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

And this helped, but why I'm getting 0 in `setText` value ?

Comment: Yes, `MainWindow::setText()` should be declared as a slot by putting it under `public slots:` section in `MainWindow` class declaration.

Comment: This helped, but why I'm getting 0 in `setText` value ?

Comment: You can also mark `setText` as `Q_INVOKABLE`, rather than making it a slot

Answer (score 0):

Your button-event is handled by the event loop that owns the MainWindow object and this same object also contains the method you wish to invoke (setText()). That means that caller and callee (or signal and slot) in your case live on the same thread, and you must not use **Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection**! To quote the manual: *Using this connection type to communicate between objects in the same thread will lead to deadlocks.*

If you intent to do processing in your *on_pushButton_clicked()* after the *setText()* method has finished, use a **Qt::DirectConnection** instead, then your *setText()* will be called as if it was a simple function, and control returns to your *clicked()* function after *setText()* finished.

If you intent to finish processing all code in your *on_pushButton_clicked()* before processing of the *setText()* function starts, use a **Qt::QueuedConnection**.

If you wish to execute *setText()* in parallel to *on_pushButton_clicked()*, then move your *setText()* method to another object (which is owned by another thread). Only in this scenario a **Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection** makes sense.